# Omnipersistence: The entity has no primary key attribute defined

Tags: java, jpa, extends, omnifaces

I am trying to use Omnipersistence for the first time on a new Maven project and get the following error in Eclipse: `The entity has no primary key attribute defined`

```
import org.omnifaces.persistence.model.TimestampedEntity;
@Entity
public class ShoppingCart extends TimestampedEntity<Long> {

    ...
}
```

While trying to figure out the issue, I happened to add a constructor with `this.id = id`, and Eclipse gave a warning that stated `id is not visible` but when I control-clicked on id, it took me to the `TimestampedEntity` class.

Comment: Please pick a question and post a [mcve]

Comment: @Mad: that's not needed. The question was fine. See abovelinked dupe for answer. This is an Eclipse quirk. You need to manually add any `@MappedSuperclass` such as `TimestampedEntity` to list of classes in `persistence.xml` as well.

Comment: @BalusC. Fair enough, but also there are two questions here.